# Problem with Linq Joins with multible keys?

Tags: linq, join

I've some errors with linq joins

my query is like that :

```
 from inv in SellServiceInvoice.All()
    join Ent in Entity.All() on new { CID = inv.EntityID, CType = inv.EntityTypeID }
    equals new { CID =(long) Ent.EntityID, CType =(long) Ent.EntityTypeID}  
    select new {...}
```

prob 1 : why must I add casting '(long)' although the types is already long!

prob 2 : it gives me the following exception:

The construtor 'Void .ctor(Int64, Int64)' is not supported

Comment: sorry , I added the exception !!

Comment: @The Knight: is you code works without casting to `long`?

Comment: No :(, and I don't know why !!

Comment: Are you sure it is really `long` and not nullable (`long?`)?

Comment: @Albin: Oh thanks, it's int !! not long, but what about prob2 !! it still gives me same exception !!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
from inv in SellServiceInvoice.All()
from Ent in Entity.All() 
where inv.EntityID = CID =(long) Ent.EntityID && 
      inv.EntityTypeID == (long)Ent.EntityTypeID
select new {...}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks very much, it works now, but I need to know what this exception for and why !? could you help ?!

Comment: @The Knight: unfortunatelly, have no idea about your exception. The example above is just your query but instead of `join` I moved the condition to `where` block.